Connecting Power pins on BGA packages
For BGA packages, I never see people tying power/GND pins together on BGA package (e.g. tying +1.1V_FPGA pins together as shown). Usually I see one ball to one via like how the GND is layout as shown.  Is it because of DFM issue?  I wonder tying together helps improve inductance or decoupling.  Thanks so much for reading this.

Hi Peter, I believe using a via per each pin effectively puts the vias in parallel, reducing the inductance. The multitude of vias also helps with thermal dissipation, etc.
